# Besondere Beugung von "Präsident"

Tags: accusative, inflection, declension

Diese Woche habe ich auf der Seite der DW einen Artikel gelesen, dessen erster Satz lautet: "*Um Brasiliens Präsident Jair Bolsonaro wird es einsamer.*"

Mir ist die Beugung des zur N-Deklination gehörenden Nomens "Präsident" sofort aufgefallen. Da die Präposition "um" immer Akkusativ verlangt, warum heißt hier nicht "um Brasiliens Präsidenten"? Hat das wohl irgendwas mit diesem vorangestellten Genitiv "Brasiliens" zu tun, oder handelt es sich hier eher um einen Fehler?

Der Artikel lässt sich übrigens hier finden: https://www.dw.com/de/brasilien-sind-bolsonaros-tage-gez%C3%A4hlt/a-57067760

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hier sind zwei Effekte im Spiel:

1. Die n-Deklination im Deutschen ist eine aussterbende Sprachform: Mehr und mehr scheint es in der gesprochenen Sprache akzeptabel (und praktiziert, außer im Genitiv), die Endungen einfach wegzulassen:

   > Ich habe einen Student [statt *Studenten*] kennengelernt.

   Das ist zwar grammatikalisch eigentlich falsch, aber inzwischen gängig. (allerdings nicht der Fall in deinem Beispiel)
2. Die n-Deklination hat eine Ausnahmeregel, die in deinem Beispiel zutrifft: *Die n-Endung fällt weg, wenn Nomen im Singular ohne einen Artikel auf eine Präposition folgen*:

   > Die Gesundheitsreform ergab einige Änderungen für Arzt und Patient.

   Dies gilt auch in der Schriftsprache, und ist genau der Fall in deinem Beispiel. Das Phänomen hat wahrscheinlich damit zu tun, dass mit Endung und ohne kongruenten Artikel nicht klar ist, ob Singular oder Plural gemeint ist - was in deinem Fall aber auch ohne Artikel einigermaßen klar ist - es gibt m.W. nur einen Präsidenten Brasiliens.

Mit dem vorangestellten Genitiv hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: Vielleicht kommt noch ein dritter Effekt hinzu. Titel und Amtsbezeichnungen wie "Präsident" könnte man als Teil des Namens betrachten, der entsprechend nicht gebeugt wird. Dann wäre "Um Präsident Bolsonaro..." vergleichbar mit "Um Abteilungsleiter Müller...". Da dürfte auch der fehlende Artikel mit hineinspielen. Schließlich hieße es mit der gebeugten Form "Um den Präsidenten Bolsonaro..." und nicht "Um Präsidenten Bolsonaro..." (das Genitivobjekt einmal ausgelassen).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Man kann ja den Namen einfach weglassen und für "Präsident" gilt immer noch dasselbe. ("Um Brasiliens Präsident wird es immer einsamer"). Kann also irgendwie nicht sein.

Comment: Aber soweit kein Artikel vor den Nomen im Singular steht, muss die n-Endung wegfallen oder eher einfach darf sie weggelassen werden? Gilt dies auch ohne die Präposition?

Comment: Nein, das gilt nur in genau der Kombination - mit Präposition, aber ohne Artikel.

Comment: Das hier vorliegende Phänomen wurde bereits - ebenfalls am Beispiel des "Präsident"! - vor einigen Jahren vom Zwiebelfisch thematisiert: https://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/zwiebelfisch/kasus-verschwindibus/

Comment: @ixolius Nur hat er leider den Fall "ohne Artikel, aber mit Präposition" vollkommen außer acht gelassen. Deswegen sind manche seiner Beispiele richtig - und manche falsch.

Comment: @tofro Gut zu wissen, als ich den Text gelesen habe, war es mir nicht aufgefallen